# Does NSView have a backgroundColor? If it does, I can't find it

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, background-color

I'm seeing all over the place online where people are referring to NSView's backgroundColor. I need to set a custom backgroundColor to my NSView, but I'm not seeing that property. I can't see it in code, or in IB. I am unable to set the background color of my simple NSView.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They must be thinking of `UIView`, which does have a `backgroundColor` property.  `NSView` does **not** have a `backgroundColor` property.

You will have to achieve your effect some other way, e.g., through subclassing `NSView`.

Comment: That is really weird that they wouldn't have an out of the box method of changing the background color of a view. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Wes: That's because `NSView`, by itself, doesn't really do anything.  It doesn't draw anything.  I have a hard time imagining a situation where you'd need to set the background color but you aren't already subclassing the view.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough NSView does not provide this (sigh). I use one consistent class I wrote myself throughout all my macOs projects. Just change the CustomView class in the Identity Inspector tab in IB to ColorView. You will then be able to set the background color in the Attribute Inspector, just like you would for a UIView. Here's the code, hope this helps!

```
import Cocoa

class ColorView: NSView
{
    @IBInspectable var backgroundColor:NSColor?

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        wantsLayer = true
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        wantsLayer = true
    }

    override func layout()
    {
        layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach it via the view's layer, e.g. (in Swift):

```
      view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
```

Strangely it can be set in the xib. In the identity inspector for the view, add the User Defined Runtime Attribute `backgroundColor`, with the Type color.